# How can I get current RailsBaseURI name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to know how I can get the `RailsBaseURI` name. I configured my application url name in `httpd.conf` as `'redmine'`. I want to retrieve this in my ruby file. I tried like this:

```
render js: "window.location.pathname=" + "'" + "/redmine/issues/#{@verifiable.issue.id}" + "'"
```

But this name (`redmine`) may vary from system to system. In another system, we are getting 404 error as the name is different there; it's `redmine1`.

My url looks like: `'http://192.19.163.125/redmine/issues/193599'`.

The other system url looks like: 'http://192.19.163.126/redmine1/issues/193599'.

Please tell me how I can get this.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in Javascript? Or in ruby?

Comment: replace redmine with `#{httpd.conf}` in your url like this. `render js: "window.location.pathname=" + "'" + "/#{httpd.conf}/issues/#{@verifiable.issue.id}" + "'"`